# need to sync exchange calendar with users home outlook calendar via iphone

Tags: microsoft-outlook, iphone, sync, exchange

The president of our company used to use a Windows Mobile phone that was able to sync to both our corporate exchange server, as well as his home computer running MS Outlook with his personal email and take the calendar items from both and sync them together, so he could view his home calendar at work and his work calendar at home.

We recently switched to using iPhones, which do not allow this sync of calendars. He is able to view both calendars on his phone, but the items from his home calendar do not sync to his work calendar the way they used to when we used a Windows Mobile phone with activesync.

Apple's MobileMe can not sync with an exchange server. Does anyone know of a solution to allow both of his calendars to sync together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i've found a solution using Google Calendar Sync (http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=89955) but it'll require the user to have a google calendar as the intermediary. If there is any solution anyone knows of to do it without this middle step, please let me know.